# Want to embed a font but cannot convert from Font Suitcase or PostScript Type 1 files

Tags: fonts, embed, font-face

I am using FontSquirrel font generator to try to generate the embedded font files so that I can use the **@font-face** in css to embed for a Website.

However, the font files I have (on Mac) are as follows and are greyed out and it is not possible to select them to convert on FontSquirrel or other converters (i.e. they don't seem to be a raw file type I can use to embed):

- PostScript Type 1 Outline Font
- Font Suitcase

Can I somehow convert these to **.otf** or **.ttf** or does anyone know of another embedding method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/)?

The GUI is horrible, and it needs X11 to run on Mac, but it's really a nice tool to convert any type of font.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I installed it, but the fonts I mentioned are not showing in the list of fonts in my font library.

Comment: Further to last comment, I have got it to load the postscript type 1 file by typing in the name in the Open Font window. It opens the font but it errors when trying to save the font as true type.

Comment: Final update in case this is of use to anyone else :) I revisited this again earlier and I think FontForge as suggested by Macmade, was the best possibility having scoured other forums and google results! 

There were errors as mentioned with FontForge, but these were individually logged and seemed to only effect some specific non-alphanumeric characters - so I managed to convert the font. I also tried downloading demo's of Fontlab studio and Fontographer and looked into one or two others, but the demo distorted characters and the license cost too much!

Comment: Is fontforge the only real option? It is a pita! :(

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't get that solution to work on Mavericks... found this great guide: http://macthoughts.net/20131112-373 - it's free, easy and works perfectly.

Comment: this almost worked for me. The file it results in for me is a .bdf instead of a .ttf

Comment: @GhostEcho odd, i use it all the time and never get an issue. Is it dfontslitter the one that exports the wrong file type?

Comment: @GhostEcho I'm experiencing the same problem. I think it comes from the font SuitCase, containing PostScript fonts and not TTF fonts. Did you solve it?

Comment: @ryancey, unfortunately not. That specific font would have been ideal in my situation, but it was taking up too much time. I ended up using a different font. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As of at least version 0.4.1 of [DFontSplitter](http://peter.upfold.org.uk/projects/dfontsplitter), the Mac version has the ability to split TrueType Collection (TTC) and Font Suitcase files in addition to Dfont files.

Comment: I just tried using this but got the following error: The error message is: ‘Can't find an appropriate resource fork in /Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/Exported Fonts/Eurostile/Eurostile'. I have no idea what a resource fork is. Curious about what should happen. I'm new at this.

Comment: I checked again. I found other instructions where I had to do another conversion before using DFontSplitter. Got it working!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting .bdf files output when I converted the font suitcase file (.ffil) to .dfont and then used dfontsplitter.

However, I found a solution to get around this.  Instead of converting the suitcase file (.ffil) to .dfont, I converted the individual fonts (.lwfn) that went with the suitcase into .dfont files.

Then, when I used dfontsplitter on these, it gave me a .pfb file for each of the individual fonts.  Then, I used an online service at http://www.freefontconverter.com/ to convert the .pfb files into fully functional .ttf files with no errors!

Comment: Just wanted to post an update.  The link I posted above no longer works with .pfb files.  However, I just used https://everythingfonts.com/pfb-to-ttf for the same purpose and it worked well.