# How can I Use a Font Suitcase with the @font-face CSS statement?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I would like to use the Eurostyle font in my Rails application. We got it a while ago and installed in on our Mac computers. The font shows up in all our applications.

This will be my first time using the @font-face CSS statement in my stylesheet. I could not find any examples using a font suitcase. I have found a few solutions on how to split the font. So far the one I found has not worked. The link below suggested using DFontSplitter but when I did I got an error which is listed below. I have no idea what this is.

[Want to embed a font but cannot convert from Font Suitcase or PostScript Type 1 files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228957/want-to-embed-a-font-but-cannot-convert-from-font-suitcase-or-postscript-type-1/25577422#25577422)

The error message is: ‘Can't find an appropriate resource fork in /Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/Exported Fonts/Eurostile/Eurostile

The only other solution I saw was very complicated and was for Mac OS 9.

Has anyone successfully used a font suitcase with the @font-face statement?  If not how do I convert this to ttf or some other font format that works on popular browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. `@font-face` is for loading individual font files, not suitcases/fontbooks/opentype collections/etc.

Long answer: there is no long answer, the short answer is all there is to it.

Convert the individual fonts you need to an opentype format, or ideally an opentype format that's been wrapped by a [WOFF](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff) (WOFF v1 has massive support, WOFF v2 not yet, it's too new), and point to those with your (possibly multiple due to multiple font styles and weights) `@font-face` rules.

Comment: I was able to find a solution to convert my font suitcase to TTF using the solution from this link below. Now I need to figure out how to code the src clause in @font-face to download the font. The font has been installed on my Mac Mini server where my Rails application is hosted.

http://macthoughts.net/20131112-373

Comment: that's easy enough. convert the `ttf` to `woff` (million online converters, or use fontforge or the like), then just put those in a web-accessible place and write your @font-face rules to point to them by URL. Unlike in the past, you no longer need "all the filetypes", just serving the single WOFF will work on all modern browsers.

Comment: I looked at FontForge and it scared me LOL. I did find this link https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff and converted my TTF fonts to WOFF and changed my stylesheet. They are working well and I guess more up to date. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to convert my font suitcase to TTF using the solution from this link below.

http://macthoughts.net/20131112-373

After converting my suitcase file I copied the TTF files into my Rails application. I changed the src value in my stylesheet to point to the font files in my application. Now people who do not have the font installed will see the font I want in my Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get ttf files from font suitcase files this way:
I opened the Font Book app on my mac (osx 10.13.2), and located the font (make sure it's installed). Select the font and click file - export fonts and select a location.
The result in my case was a ttc file. I could convert this file easily with an online converter like [this one](https://transfonter.org/ttc-unpack).